# Php Display While Loop From Function

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question regarding displaying the contents of a function, this function displaying a while loop.

Here is a function within my model:

```
function get_results($id)
{
    $stmt = "select * where ... "
    $stmt = $this->BEAR->Database->query($stmt);

    $result = '';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))
    {
        $result .= '<div>';
        $result .= $row['name'];
        $result .= '</div>';
    }

    $this->BEAR->Template->setData('loop', $result, FALSE);
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
    $BEAR->Webprofile->get_results(Template->getData('id'));
```

And this is my view:

```
<?php echo $this->getData('loop');?>
```

This displays the Loop within my view with no problem. But what I wish for is not to have any HTMl within my Model, Is there anyway of doing this (As this can cause a large amount of HTML in my Model). Maybe a way I can set the data within the Model and then get the data within my view.

I tried setting within the Model functions while loop individually like the following:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))
    {
       $this->BEAR->Template->setData('name', $row['name']);
       $this->BEAR->Template->setData('name', $row['age']);
    }
```

Then call the function in the Controller and call each setData, but this only displayed the first result not the full while loop of contents.

Therefore I wish to display all the contents of my while loop in my view (with HTML) but wish my function to just be getting and setting the Data. Can this be done? Any thoughts or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand, you basicly want to get a live html output from your PHP? If so, AJAX is for you.

Comment: No, basically from my model to get a fetch data and set each row within a while loop. Then call the function within my model and display the set rows from my model individually.

Comment: What happens if you call $model->get_results from 2 different controllers and then a year from now you want to change the output format in one of the controllers... you can't because you are creating the output in the model. 

Your model should just return the dataset. Your controller should call the model->get_results and pass the resulting dataset to the view (template). 

In the example above you are combining the view within the model

Comment: Which framework are you using? Code Igniter?

Comment: @Matt I understand that, hence why Im asking the question ;) I wanting to know a way of doing what you just stated. Ally Im not using a framwork, essentially have a MVC framework created by myself:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply some discipline to your MVC.  Your models need to return raw data.  It should return only objects or arrays of data.  The key is consistency.

Your views need to include all the code to add your html formatting.  Having a view that simply calls a model function you wrote that spits out a div or an ordered list, makes the entire concept of the view useless.  Your views should provide all the HTML code.

Since you're using PHP, you can easily drop in and out of HTML.

Start with something like this in your model:

```
function get_results($id)
{
    $stmt = "select * where ... "
    $stmt = $this->BEAR->Database->query($stmt);

    $results = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))
    {
        $results[] = $row['name'];       
    }
    return results; 
}
```

From there, you should be able to figure out that your controller should call this function, and pass the $results into your view/template along with the specific view file for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_results($id)
{
    $stmt = "select * where ... "
    $stmt = $this->BEAR->Database->query($stmt);

    $result = '';
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt);
    return $result;
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
 $this->BEAR->Template->setData('loop', $model->get_results($id), FALSE);
```

Then in your template

```
foreach($rows as $row){
     ....do something with each row
}
```

full example of how to get the data from the model and then pass to the template

```
class MyController {
    function controller_showResults(){
        $model = new Model();
        $results = $model->get_results($_GET['id']);
        $this->BEAR->Template->setData('loop', $results, FALSE);
    }
}
```

Now the view assuming that the first argument to setData in template is a variable passed to the view and that variable is $results

```
<?php foreach($loop as $l): ?>
    <div><?php echo $l['name'] ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Surely this wouldn't work as im not fetching the data within the View, as I would need to use $this->Template->getData('loop'); surely?

Comment: Let me update my answer for better representation of what I mean

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt, I understand that part.. Setting the data, but the foreach part do i not need to get that data, by using a getter... being this : $this->Template->getData('loop'); Thanks for your time :)

Comment: no, this is the view
$this->BEAR->Template

I would pass the data to the view and then process the loop in the view. You can have a strickly HTML view. In that case you would create your html in the controller, but the model would still only return an array for the dataset. Let me update my answer...

Comment: take a look at codeigniter... You can set it up very fast and get a good handle on how that frameworks handles the passing of variables from models to views.

Comment: Hi Matt, I think you are right I might have to download and take apart Codeignitor and see how they do it. the above code churned out some errors, thanks for your time anyway buddy.